# Do I need both the boarding pass and the tickets?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, ryanair, check-in

I'm about to travel with Ryanair for the first time and have a hard time understanding the rules.

I know that I need to do an online check-in and to print a boarding pass (or do it at the airport and pay extra fee), and I already did that.

However, what I'm confused about is that the *only* document I have right now is the boarding pass. There are no tickets, and no way to print tickets on the website. My boarding pass has my name and ID, the ID, date and time of the flight and the seat number, but, for instance, the price of the flight is not indicated.

An I expected to have an additional ticket, or the boarding pass is the only thing I need to have to board a plane?

If I need a ticket, would a confirmation e-mail Ryanair sent me (and which contains the price paid for the tickets) be enough?

Comment: Boarding pass is enough, but I'm pretty sure you must be able to obtain an e-ticket or a receipt. The ticket number and/or registration number are usually needed to do related stuff online, which includes printing receipts, online check-in and buying extra services.

Comment: "...and pay extra fee..." - Ryanair has only one "rule": *everything* (except the bare minimum legal requirements of the aviation regulations) *costs extra* ;)

Comment: Are boarding passes and tickets separate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**You need to have that printed boarding pass and a valid ID, e.g. a passport. That's all.**

Source: Personal experience. I fly Ryanair several times a year.

Comment: The only reason to print out your electronic tickets is when you have problems checking in or printing our boarding passes.

Comment: No need to print them out. Just have the confirmation e-mail or confirmation e-mail in your phone.

Comment: @Hilmar good point, more info [here](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Mobile-boarding-passes#0-1) about their mobile app. Do you use that or have the boarding pass as .pdf on your phone?